# Patching class does not work its definition is get from dict

Tags: pytest, patch

I have a problem with patching, how can I patch A class properly?

a.py

```py
class A:
    pass
```

plugin.py

```py
from a import A

CONFIG = {'aenum': A}

def do():
   instance = CONFIG['aenum']()  # the A class is NOT patched using this
   # instance = A()  # the test passes with this
   return instance.auth()
```

test.py  (using pytest to run)

```py
from unittest.mock import Mock, patch
import plugin

def test_do():
    a_instance_mock = Mock()
    a_instance_mock.auth.return_value = 42
    with patch("plugin.A", return_value=a_instance_mock):
        assert plugin.do() == 42
```

Answer (score 1):

`patch` overrides only the specific item from given namespace; the class name is patched AFTER a module is imported, not in the importation time.

That is why the CONFIG["aenum"] is left untouched.

Use [patch.dict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.patch.dict) instead

```py
from unittest.mock import Mock, patch
from plugin import do

def test_do():
    a_instance_mock = Mock()
    a_instance_mock.authenticate.return_value = 42
    a_class_mock = Mock(return_value=a_instance_mock)
    with patch.dict("plugin.CONFIG", {"aenum": a_class_mock}):
        assert do() == 42
```